# HTML Select - change src Audio on select with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, select, audio, src

I have a menu select with 3 different song to choose. I am trying to switch the song when I select the track in the menu drop.

I am trying using jQuery to do that but with no results.

this is the code

HTML

```
<select id="changeselection" name="change-selection">

<option id="change1" value="change1" selected>Song 1</option>
<option id="change2" value="change2">Song 2</option>
<option id="change3" value="change3">Song 3</option>

</select>

<audio id="audio1" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg" controls preload loop>
<source id="audiochange" type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3">
        Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#change1").on("click",function(){
     var src = "http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3";
     $("#audiochange").attr("src",src);
 });

$("#change2").on("click",function(){
     var src = "http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3";
     $("#audiochange").attr("src",src);
 });

$("#change3").on("click",function(){
     var src = "http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3";
     $("#audiochange").attr("src",src);
 });
    });
```

Any Advice?

here the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/BAR35/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/salvonostrato/BAR35/4/

Solved Thanks

HTML

```
<select id="changeselection" name="change-selection">

<option id="change1" value="change1" selected>Song 1</option>
<option id="change2" value="change2">Song 2</option>
<option id="change3" value="change3">Song 3</option>

</select>

<audio id="audio1" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg" controls preload loop>
<source id="audiochange" type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3">
        Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#changeselection").on("change",function(){

    if($(this).val()=="change2"){
  var src = "http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3";
        console.log('change2');
    }

    else if ($(this).val()=="change3"){
      var src = "http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3";
        console.log('change3');
    }  

    else {
      var src = "http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3";
        console.log('change1');
    }


  audio=$("#audio1");
  $("#audio1").attr("src",src);

  audio[0].pause();
  audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element
  audio[0].play();

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to below code after changing the source of audio.

```
 audio=$("#audiochange");
 audio[0].pause();
 audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element
 audio[0].play();
```

also you have incorrect js which is not going to work on option change. try this:

```
$("#changeselection").on("change",function(){
 if($(this).val()=="change1")
  var src = "http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3";
 else if($(this).val()=="change2"){
   var src = "http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3";
 else 
   var src = "http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3";
  $("#audiochange").attr("src",src);
  audio=$("#audiochange");
  audio[0].pause();
  audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element
  audio[0].play();
});});
```

Comment: Hi Milind, thank you for your advice. I have tried as you said however I get an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'"  Here the fiddle    http://jsfiddle.net/salvonostrato/BAR35/1/

Comment: Also it says "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'audio[0].pause()')"